# Prove $ 2\cdot5\cdot11\cdot19\cdot23\cdot29\cdot31>3^{16} $

Tags: inequality, factorial, catalan-numbers

I recently came across the following problem:

If $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ is the $n$-th catalan number, then prove that for all $n\ge 17$:
$$
C_n>3^n
$$
How the induction step works is quite clear, but the base case troubles me (I want to do it by hand):

If we cancel down the appearing fraction, it comes down to proving:
$$
2\cdot5\cdot11\cdot19\cdot23\cdot29\cdot31>3^{16}
$$
I tired to bound the numbers on the right hand side by powers of three, but nothing seemed to work. Then I thought maybe it isn't feasible in a reasonable amount of time and got the following result:

Even if we take the inequality to the power of $1000$ and find the optimal integer bounds $(2\cdot5\cdot11)^{1000}>3^{4278}$, $(19\cdot23)^{1000}>3^{5534}$ and $(29\cdot31)^{1000}>3^{6190}$ we only obtain $2\cdot5\cdot11\cdot19\cdot23\cdot29\cdot31>3^{16.002}$.

So it seems indeed that it isn't feasible. However, can you think of a way to prove it; maybe using starlings approximation?

Comment: These numbers aren't so large, one can multiply on paper. It's not awfully clever, but it gets the job done.

Comment: The left side is only about $0.4\%$ larger than the right, so any estimation technique would need to be very sharp. You can always just multiply each side to its decimal representation. You get 8-digit numbers, so not terribly large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one?
$$
\frac{11.23}{3^5}\frac{2.5}{3^2}\frac{29}{3^3}\frac{31}{3^3}\frac{19}{3^2} > 3
$$
To prove that:
$$
A = \frac{11.23}{3^5}\frac{2.5}{3^2}\frac{29}{3^3}\frac{31}{3^3}\frac{19}{3^2} = (1+\frac{10}{3^5})(1+\frac{1}{3^2})(1+\frac{2}{3^3})(1+\frac{4}{3^3})(2+\frac{1}{3^2})
$$
and
$$
(1+\frac{10}{3^5})(1+\frac{1}{3^2})= 1+\frac{10}{3^5}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{10}{3^7}>1+\frac{10}{3^5}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{9}{3^7}=1+\frac{38}{3^5}
$$
also
$$
(1+\frac{2}{3^3})(1+\frac{4}{3^3})=1+\frac{6}{3^3}+\frac{8}{3^6}>1+\frac{2}{3^2}+\frac{6}{3^6}=1+\frac{56}{3^5}
$$
so replacing we get 
$$
 A > (1+\frac{38}{3^5})(1+\frac{56}{3^5})(2+\frac{1}{3^2}) = (1+\frac{94}{3^5}+\frac{38.56}{3^{10}})(2+\frac{1}{3^2}) > (1+\frac{94}{3^5}+\frac{38.54}{3^{10}})(2+\frac{1}{3^2}) = (1+\frac{94}{3^5}+\frac{38.2}{3^{7}})(2+\frac{1}{3^2}) > (1+\frac{94}{3^5}+\frac{25}{3^{6}})(2+\frac{1}{3^2}) = (1+\frac{307}{3^6})(2+\frac{1}{3^2})= 2 + \frac{307.2}{3^6}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{307}{3^8} > 2 + \frac{307.2}{3^6}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{306}{3^8} = 3
$$
Done

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate as follows:

$29\times 31=900-1$, $19\times 23 =441-4$, $2\times 5 \times 11=110$

So $$2\times 5\times 11\times 19\times 23\times29\times 31=110\times 900\times 441-110\times 4\times 900-110\times 441+4\times 110$$

The leading term is about 1% too high by comparison with the other terms, and is equal to $3^4\times 110\times 100\times 49=3^4\times 539,000$

Now $3^6=729$ and $729^2=531,441$ (or do $81^3=6561\times 81$ if it is easier).

You can put the pieces together to get a good enough estimate. Possibly easier to do the straightforward complete calculation, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof using logarithms and exponentials that gets by with calculations up to $3^{10}$:

$$
2\cdot5\cdot11\cdot19\cdot23\cdot29\cdot31\gt3^{16}\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{10}{3^2}\cdot\frac{253}{3^5}\cdot\frac{29}{3^3}\cdot\frac{31}{3^3}\gt\frac{3^3}{19}\\
\Leftrightarrow\left(1+\frac1{3^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{10}{3^5}\right)\left(1+\frac2{3^3}\right)\left(1+\frac4{3^3}\right)\gt\frac{3^3}{19}
$$

With $\log(1+x)\gt x-\frac12x^2$ for $x\gt0$, we get

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\log\left(\left(1+\frac1{3^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{10}{3^5}\right)\left(1+\frac2{3^3}\right)\left(1+\frac4{3^3}\right)\right)\\
&\gt&\frac1{3^2}+\frac{10}{3^5}+\frac2{3^3}+\frac4{3^3}-\frac12\left(\left(\frac1{3^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{10}{3^5}\right)^2+\left(\frac2{3^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac4{3^3}\right)^2\right)\\
&=&\frac{41777}{2\cdot3^{10}}\\
&=&\frac{19}{2\cdot3^3}+\frac{112}{3^{10}}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

and then exponentiating again and using $\mathrm e^x\gt1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3$ yields

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left(1+\frac1{3^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{10}{3^5}\right)\left(1+\frac2{3^3}\right)\left(1+\frac4{3^3}\right)\\
&\gt&\exp\left(\frac{19}{2\cdot3^3}+\frac{112}{3^{10}}\right)\\
&\gt&1+\frac{19}{2\cdot3^3}+\frac{108}{3^{10}}+\frac12\left(\frac{19}{2\cdot3^3}\right)^2+\frac16\left(\frac{18}{2\cdot3^3}\right)^3\\
&=&\frac{24875}{2^3\cdot3^7}\\
&\gt&\frac{24867}{2^3\cdot3^7}\\
&=&\frac{307}{2^3\cdot3^3}\\
&\gt&\frac{3^3}{19}\;.
\end{eqnarray}